# How to get correct encoding on R on SQL Server when executing external script in SSMS?

Tags: r, encoding, sql-server-2019

We have installed R 4.1 on one server and it produces gibberish when running external script through SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). We used this guide when installing: [Install an R custom runtime for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/custom-runtime-r?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=platform-windows)

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language =N'myR',
    @script=N'
print(R.version);'
```

STDOUT message(s) from external script:
��_��
��platform��       ��x86_64-w64-mingw32��
��arch��           ��x86_64��
��os��             ��mingw32��
��system��         ��x86_64, mingw32��
��status��         ����
��major��          ��4��
��minor��          ��1.0��
��year��           ��2021��
��month��          ��05��
��day��            ��18��
��svn rev��        ��80317��
��language��       ��R��
��version.string�� ��R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)��
��nickname��       ��Camp Pontanezen��

If I run something returning a resultset in a grid, everything seem to be fine.

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'myR'
    , @script = N'
OutputDataSet <- data.frame(installed.packages()[,c("Package", "Version", "Depends", "License", "LibPath")]);'
WITH result sets((
            Package NVARCHAR(255)
            , Version NVARCHAR(100)
            , Depends NVARCHAR(4000)
            , License NVARCHAR(1000)
            , LibPath NVARCHAR(2000)
            ));
```

[image: SSMS Resultset is ok]

If I run same script in RGui.exe, it's also fine

> print(R.version);
> _
> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
> arch           x86_64
> os             mingw32
> system         x86_64, mingw32
> status
> major          4
> minor          1.0
> year           2021
> month          05
> day            18
> svn rev        80317
> language       R
> version.string R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
> nickname       Camp Pontanezen

An easier sample:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language =N'myR',
    @script=N'
print("ÅÄÖ");'
```

Gives:

```
"��Ã…Ã„Ã–��"
```

We're using the same SSMS towards another R Server, with bundled version of R (2.x or something) then it displays correctly.

Encoding on the server seem to be correct, but not the resulting output when it's run in SSMS and result as a "string". How can one correct this?

Sys.getenv() (related to R) on the machine **not** working:

> R_ARCH                  /x64 R_ARCH_BIN              /x64 R_BROWSER
> R_BZIPCMD               bzip2 R_CMD                   R CMD
> R_COMPILED_BY           gcc 8.3.0 R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES
> datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats R_DOC_DIR
> D:/RCompile/recent/R-4.0.3/doc R_GAMS_SYSDIR
> d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs215/GAMS/win64 R_GC_GROWINCRFRAC
> 0.2 R_GSCMD                 C:/Progra~2/gs/gs9.21/bin/gswin32c.exe R_GZIPCMD               gzip R_HOME                  C:/Program
> Files/R/R-4.1.0 R_INCLUDE_DIR
> D:/RCompile/recent/R-4.0.3/include R_INSTALL_PKG           RInside
> R_INSTALL_TAR           tar.exe R_LIBS_USER
> C:/Users/CRAN/Documents/R/win-library/4.0 R_MAX_NUM_DLLS          153
> R_OSTYPE                windows R_PACKAGE_NAME          RInside
> R_PAPERSIZE             a4 R_PAPERSIZE_USER        a4 R_PARALLEL_PORT
> random R_RD4PDF                times,inconsolata,hyper R_SCRIPT_LEGACY
> yes R_SESSION_TMPDIR
> C:/WINDOWS/ServiceProfiles/MSSQLLaunchpad$MABI_SQLSERVER/AppData/Local/Packages/38af79a5ed4e7cad1e6ad6e9e57a562d-appcontainer1/AC/Temp
> R_SHARE_DIR             D:/RCompile/recent/R-4.0.3/share R_UNZIPCMD
> unzip R_USER                  C:/Users/CRAN/Documents R_VERSION
> 4.0.3 R_ZIPCMD                zip

Sys.getenv() (related to R) on the machine working:

> R_ARCH                  /x64 R_COMPILED_BY           gcc 4.9.3 R_HOME
> D:/ProgramData/INSTANS01/R R_LIBS_USER
> D:\ProgramData\INSTANS01\Temp-R\Appcontainer1\FF5697C0-8563-40AE-85B0-3DDE0B6C59C4/R/win-library/3.5
> R_USER
> D:\ProgramData\INSTANS01\Temp-R\Appcontainer1\FF5697C0-8563-40AE-85B0-3DDE0B6C59C4
> R_ZIPCMD
> D:/ProgramData/INSTANS01/R/library/RevoScaleR/utils/infoZip/zip.exe

Comment: Maybe R produces output in UTF-8 but SMSS is expecting the stdout (console) output to be in UTF-16? https://www.google.com/search?q=SSMS+console+encoding

Comment: It could have been that, but if we're using the same SSMS towards another R Server, with bundled version of R (2.x or something) then it displays correctly.

Comment: What does `Sys.getlocale()` return?

Comment: Sys.getlocale() returns: "��LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252��". Even then with strange characters.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem in the opposite direction: when taking `.sql` files I created in SSMS (on Windows 10), trying to read them into R, and executing those SQL commands via the `RODBC` package in R.  While R uses ISO-8859-1 encoding by default, SSMS files are saved in Windows-1252 encoding ("Western European (Windows)") by default; a `.r` script can be saved in the latter encoding by selecting `File` > `Save with Encoding...` > `WINDOWS-1252`.  Is this a helpful clue for your situation?

Comment: My problem is the result from R is encoded incorrectly. If I use the same SSMS againt one version of R (2.x) the result is encoded correctly, if I use the same SSMS on a another R Server (4.0.1) the result is encoded incorrectly (in the meaning it SSMS doesn't show it correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, and not finding any solution, we downgraded to 3.6.3 and it worked as expected. It seems to be a bug/difference in R 4.1 regarding encoding.

Answer (score -1):

SMSS has a default encoding of UTF-16. You should be able to change the default encoding in R to that or this [article](https://joehanna.com/sql-server/changing-the-default-encoding-of-sql-files-in-ssms/) details how to change it within SSMS. I'm not sure if this will work but at this point, it can't hurt to try.

Best of luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is that I use the same SSMS against two different SQL Server with R, one returns correct encoding and the other incorrect, so the change ought to be on the server side, not SSMS side.